# In which sense guards are better than imperative-if? (new to haskell )

Tags: haskell

For the third time in my life I'm trying to learn Haskell, this time through [Learn you a Haskell...](http://learnyouahaskell.com).
When the author explains guards, he shows this example:

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> String 
bmiTell bmi  
| bmi <= 18.5 = "You're underweight, you emo, you!"  
| bmi <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal. Pffft, I bet you're ugly!"  
| bmi <= 30.0 = "You're fat! Lose some weight, fatty!"  
| otherwise   = "You're a whale, congratulations!"
```

and says

> This is very reminiscent of a big if else tree in imperative languages, only this is far better and more readable. While big if else trees are usually frowned upon, sometimes a problem is defined in such a discrete way that you can't get around them. Guards are a very nice alternative for this.

I can see guards are more readable, but I don't get why that syntax is "far better"
It is more flexible? It is more powerful? What is the big advantage of guards?

My big issue it is probably the sentence

> While big if else trees are usually frowned upon, sometimes a problem is defined in such a discrete way that you can't get around them

Can anyone give an example of that?

Comment: Apart from being more readable guards don't add anything.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: they do add something: pattern guards, which cannot be done with simple `if` `then` `else` – nor with `case` `of`, but only with a combination of both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don gives the primary motivations for using guards, but in addition to that they also combine nicely with pattern matching. If all guards on a pattern fail it drops through to the next pattern, so you can check patterns and conditions simultaneously without having lots of duplicate fall-through cases. Here's a (very artificial) example:

```
expandRange x (Just lo, Just hi) | hi < lo = (Just x, Just x)
expandRange x (Just lo, hi) | x < lo = (Just x, hi)
expandRange x (lo, Just hi) | x > hi = (lo, Just x)
expandRange _ range = range
```

If we think of `Nothing` as being unbounded, this takes an element to compare and either "expands" a negative range to only that element, moves a lower/upper bound to include the element, or leaves the range unchanged if the element is already included.

Now, consider how you'd write the above without using guards! How many times would you end up duplicating a branch that's conceptually the same because the patterns differed? And yes, I realize this small example could be rewritten to avoid the issue entirely, but that's not always possible (or desirable).

This style of definition is, to my mind, the most significant thing you can express using guards that, while still possible, would be horrendously more verbose and much harder to read if it were written as a mixture of (unguarded) pattern cases and `if` expressions.

Comment: There seems to be a consensus in the community about this being the right answer. So I learned two things: In most cases guards are just more readable if's, but their true power reveals when you combine with pattern matching. Haskell for me is like a block of knowledge: you get it all together or you just don't get it.

Comment: @PabloGrisafi: Also, being "just more readable" is nothing to take lightly! Being simultaneously succinct, readable, and expressive is what gives high-level languages their value--and all three are absolutely necessary.

Comment: You are right, being readable is very important. What I was trying to say is that, besides the pattern matching combination you showed, guards are pretty much the same concept as if/else in imperative languages. Haskell is really different and strange for my imperative mindset, but guards are not that foreign after all.

Comment: @PabloGrisafi: True. Same goes for pattern matches, really--neither is inherently functional (and in some ways they're the opposite). In fact, I've sometimes wished that imperative languages would include pattern matching (on algebraic data types) and guards--they'd be similar to the typical `switch` or `case` constructs, but *so* much more useful.

Answer (score 7):

Guards are syntactically lighter for:

- many distinct cases
- nested cases

Compare:

```
describeLetter c
   | c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' = "Lower case"
   | c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' = "Upper case"
   | otherwise            = "Not an ASCII letter"
```

with:

```
describeLetter c =
    if c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'
        then "Lower case"
        else if c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'
            then "Upper case"
            else "Not an ASCII letter"
```

The rule part is clearer syntactically and easier to maintain.

Additionally, they compose well with view patterns to yield a pleasing syntax.

```
   f x | Just t <- bar x = Right (f t)
       | otherwise       = Left "some error case"
```

for example.

Comment: the increasing indentation is not necessary though. You could align it all up vertically.

Comment: Is the `f` in `Right (f t)` in the last example correct? It seems you'd have an infinitely-recursive type.

Answer (score 2):

Any problem with a lot of if's around the place could gainfully be visualized as a decision diagram. A piece of the decision diagram for the LYAH example you cite would go:

```
                 .
                / \
               /   \
              /bmi? \
              \     /
               \   /
             /  \ /  \
            /  /   \  \
           /   |   |   \
          /    |   |    \
         /     |   |     \
        /      |   |      \
< 18.5 /18.5-25|   | 25-30 \ > 30
      /        |   |        \
    ...       ... ...       ...
```

The big advantage of guards is that they let the structure of the syntax reflect the structure of the decision diagram. If you all you had was if-then-else, then you would have to implement the above decision diagram with a series of nested if, ie to encode a multi-branch choice with a cascade of two-branch choices. Nested if's obscure the high-level idea of your algorithm.

Now, what I think the author of LYAH was getting at in the sentence you quote, is that sometimes you can't do better with guards than you can with nested if-then-else. But that's only true when choices are interdependent, ie when your decision diagram contains many diamond boxes (choices), each with only two branches, and can't be rewritten any other way. Notice that in the `bmiTell` example, each branch is independent of the other, in that the BMI can only fall within the 4 categories, neither of which overlap with any other.

Answer (score 0):

Guards are just more visually apparent and are less verbose ⁄ have less "noise" about them.

Compare:

```
bmiTell bmi
 | bmi <= 18.5 = "................................."
 | bmi <= 25.0 = "..........................................."
 | bmi <= 30.0 = "...................................."
 | otherwise   = "................................"

bmiTell bmi =
 if       bmi <= 18.5 then "................................."
 else if  bmi <= 25.0 then "..........................................."
 else if  bmi <= 30.0 then "...................................."
 else                      "................................"
```

(plus, what [C.A. McCann said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12803297/849891) about the fall-through cases). :)

Comment: But note: this is not idiomatic Haskell.

Comment: @DonStewart that's subjective in this case, I think. Sometimes you need such a construct in the middle of a function and you don't want to define a separate function just so you can write it down with guards.

Comment: Another option in such cases is the new [multi-way if syntax](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if) added in GHC 7.6.1.